# Post a tweet with Android API

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I've been searching for a way to post a tweet with my Android application, but all the things I've found don't work.

I have to admit that Twitter's API isn't so simple to understand, but my code isn't really long, and I don't see where is my mistake.

This is my code:

```
public class PartagerTwitter extends Activity {

    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer httpOauthConsumer;
    private OAuthProvider httpOauthprovider;
    public final static String consumerKey = XXX;
    public final static String consumerSecret = XXX;
    private final String CALLBACKURL = "myapp://twitactivity";
    private Twitter twitter;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            httpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            httpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                    "https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
            "https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
            String authUrl = httpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(httpOauthConsumer, CALLBACKURL);

            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        super.onNewIntent(intent);  
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        Log.i("test", uri.toString());  
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACKURL)) {
            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
            try {
                httpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(httpOauthConsumer, verifier);     
                twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

                RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACKURL); 
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken);
                String token = accessToken.getToken(), 
                secret = accessToken.getTokenSecret();

                accessToken = new AccessToken(token,secret);
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getOAuthAuthorizedInstance(consumerKey,consumerSecret,accessToken);
                twitter.updateStatus("My First Status Update");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, my keys aren't XXX.
And another question, is it possible, after login, to close the Twitter window and bring my activity to the foreground?

Answer (score 5):

Please check [the following blog post](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/13/guide-to-integrating-twitter-android-application/) for a complete end-to-end guide for posting to Twitter from an Android app.

It also includes a working Android sample in [Github](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample).

Answer (score 0):

Create your app with read/write permission in Twitter dev site, generate access token for your application.

use the following code to update the status

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String CONSUMER_KEY = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY";
    String CONSUMER_SECRET = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET";
    String ACCESS_SECRET = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET";
    String ACCESS_TOKEN = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";

    // Consumer
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

    // Access Token
    AccessToken accessToken = null;
    accessToken = new AccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

    // Posting Status
    Status status = null;
    try {
        status = twitter.updateStatus("YOUR_STATUS");
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Successfully updated the status: "
            + status.getText());
}
```